# How to fix: loops wont run to completion

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, nested-loops

I am trying to search for a set of words in a col and add either a yes or no at the end of a row. The script runs for the first few entries but it stalls halfway.

I am using textFinder to do the search and extracting the row of the results so that I can edit the yes and no.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({ name: "test", functionName: "test" });
  ss.addMenu("Commands", menuEntries);
}

function test() {
  var backupCol = 2
  var dataStartRow = 1
  var row;
  var searchString;
  var textfinder;
  var searchResults;
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("input");
  var dataLastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  dataSheet.getRange(dataStartRow, backupCol, dataLastRow).setValue("NO");
  for (var i = 0; i < yesArr.length; i++) {
    searchString = yesArr[i];
    textfinder = dataSheet.createTextFinder(searchString);
    searchResults = textfinder.findAll(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
      row = searchResults[i].getRow();
      dataSheet.getRange(row, backupCol).setValue("YES");
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the outputs of all those entries that include the values of yesArr to have a yes in col B of the row. but the actual output only works till halfway

Comment: how big is your spreadsheet, cost it might be too big and you will need to do this computation in two parts

Comment: I wouldn't use "i" as both indexs in a nested For loop, it will very likely get confused. Change your second for loop to be an "x"

Comment: @CarrotHead please provide your sheet screenshot so, we can identify that.

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly oh yeah what a rookie mistake i've made! changing it to x solved the problem thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies within your nested `for-loops`.

Using `i` as an index in both loops creates problems for the compiler.

Changing your second `for-loops` index to `x` will solve the problem.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < yesArr.length; i++) {
    searchString = yesArr[i];
    textfinder = dataSheet.createTextFinder(searchString);
    searchResults = textfinder.findAll(); 
    for (var x = 0; x < searchResults.length; x++) {
      row = searchResults[x].getRow();
      dataSheet.getRange(row, backupCol).setValue("YES");
    }
  }
```